# sort based on other array multi dimentional

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have products that have id,color and cable size.I want to respect the order of cable size array with product ids 
like this:

```
cable Array
(
    [5619] => 10 - Inch
    [5552] => 10 - Foot
    [8211] => 10 - Inch
    [5733] => 10 - Foot
)
```

so this cable array is like our sort map what ever product we have in this example should have 10-inch first and 10-foot next and they come with the product ids.

then I have colors

```
product Array
(

    [Green] => Array
        (
            [5552] => 10 - Foot
            [5619] => 10 - Inch
        )

    [Pink] => Array
        (
            [5733] => 10 - Foot
            [8211] => 10 - Inch
        )

    [Black] => Array
        (
            [4564] => 10 - Foot
        )

)
```

in this example, when we have more than one size for a color it should be ordered based on the cable array pink and green should be:

```
[Pink] => Array
        (
            [8211] => 10 - Inch
            [5733] => 10 - Foot

        )
because 8211 came before 5733 in cable array.
[Green] => Array
            (
             [5619] => 10 - Inch   
             [5552] => 10 - Foot
            )
 as well because 5619 came before 5552 in cable array.
```

I did this:

```
function OrderSizeAndColorByMerging($cablesizes, $productarray) {
    foreach ($cablesizes as $id => $size):
        foreach ($productarray as $color => $sizes):
            if ($sizes[$id]):
                $productarray[$color] = $cablesizes;
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endforeach;
    return $productarray;
}
```

but it is wrong, not sure how I can achieve it.

Comment: honestly i cant understand the way you want the sort to be done, if you could explain your question again, that would be nice.

Comment: @QuakeCore I have the cable size 10-inch,10-foot and I have array of products, but 10-inch and 10foot are not in the right order I want to have 10-inch first and then 10foot next as you see they are not ordered now so I need to order them in someway and the cable array is of help because it has them ordered.

Comment: I tried to explain more now.

Answer (score 1):

```
   foreach( $cable as $key => $value ){
      foreach ($product as $keyarray){

    if (array_key_exists( $key , $keyarray ))
    {
    echo array_key_exists( $key , $keyarray );
    unset($keyarray[$key]);
    array_unshift($arr ,$key=>value);// not sure if this is ever going to work, but i am giving u a general idea (never tested it)
    break;
    }
    }
    }
    print_r($array2);
```

Comment: do you mean $keyarray by $arr? and where is $array2?! and by value you mean $value?!

Comment: hey your code helped me to solve my problem but your code has flaws so I will post an answer here.  also +1 for you.

Comment: @Nickparsa thanks for your understanding m8, and i would love to see your solution.

Comment: thank you very much the unset idea was so helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

as QuakeCore mentioned in his code I had to unset the array inside of colors and then assign them again. so now my code is working, hope it can help some peers in future:

```
function OrderSizeAndColorByMerging($cablesizes, $productarray) {

    foreach ($cablesizes as $id => $size):
        foreach ($productarray as $color=>$array):
    if (array_key_exists($id, $array)) {
         unset($productarray[$color][$id]);
         $productarray[$color][$id]=$size;
            }
        endforeach;
    endforeach;

    return $productarray;
}
```